# Make dependency rule does not execute

Tags: makefile, dependencies

What I am trying to achieve: a make rule that would create the virtual environment for a script, activate it, and install package dependencies. (I've created a repo with files needed to recreate, for convenience).

Here is my Makefile:

```
venv:
    @echo VENV
    virtualenv $@ -p python2

foo_requirements: requirements.txt venv .FORCE
    @echo PIP
    ( . venv/bin/activate && pip install -r $< )

.PHONY: foo_requirements

FOO_CMD_SCRIPT = foo.py

FOO_CMD = . venv/bin/activate && python2 $(FOO_CMD_SCRIPT)

$(FOO_CMD_SCRIPT): foo_requirements

#--- Usage ---
all: $(FOO_CMD_SCRIPT)
    $(FOO_CMD)

.FORCE:
```

The target `all` is there only for testing, in real life I would put the content in a `foo.mk` file, and include that from another makefile.

What I expect:

- `make all` looks at the dependency `FOO_CMD_SCRIPT` for (actually a filename to a file on disk). Dependency is the `foo_requirements` rule (`PHONY`)
- rule `foo_requirements` has file dependency `requirements.txt` and `venv`. There is `.FORCE` too in here, because I don't know how to check if package installation is already done. So what I think should happen is: 1. nothing for dependency `requirements.txt` (file exists, no rule) 2. run the rule for `venv` if it does not exist.
- when `venv` rule has run and the directory is created, run the actual content of the rule: `pip install`.
- after that, the dependencies for `all` should be finished, and the actual commands should run.

What actually happens:

- `venv` gets created alright
- `pip` never runs
- the actual command never runs

Why doesn't the content of the rule `foo_requirements` run?

Likewise, the `all` rule content never runs.

Result:

```
$ make
VENV
virtualenv venv -p python2
created virtual environment CPython2.7.18.final.0-64 in 46ms
  creator CPython2Posix(dest=/home/gauthier/tmp/test_mk/venv, clear=False, no_vcs_ignore=False, global=False)
  seeder FromAppData(download=False, pip=bundle, setuptools=bundle, wheel=bundle, via=copy, app_data_dir=/home/gauthier/.local/share/virtualenv)
    added seed packages: pip==20.3.4, pkg_resources==0.0.0, setuptools==44.1.1, wheel==0.34.2
  activators BashActivator,CShellActivator,FishActivator,PowerShellActivator,PythonActivator
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't tell it otherwise, `make` will always build the first target in the makefile (along with any of its prerequisites) and then stop.

The first target in your makefile is `venv` and it has no prerequisites, so that target is built then make stops.

You can run `make <target>` to run a specific target, for example `make all`.

Or you can put the `all` target as the first one in the makefile.

Or you can add `.DEFAULT_GOAL: all` in your makefile.

See [How make Processes a Makefile](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/How-Make-Works.html)

Comment: So silly of me, I just remembered that too. I was going to delete the question, but since you took the time to answer, I'll let it be. Thanks.